# Accessing data in structures without loops

Tags: matlab, struct, anonymous-function

I have a set of strings `vals`, for example:

```
vals = {'AD', 'BC'}
```

I also have a struct `info`, inside of which are structs nested in fields corresponding to the elements in the array `vals` (that would be 'AD' and 'BC' in this example), each in turn storing a number in a field named `lastcontract`.

I can use a `for` loop to extract `lastcontract` for each of the `vals` like this:

```
for index = 1:length(vals)
    info.(vals{index}).lastcontract
end
```

I'd like to find a way of doing this without a loop if at all possible, but I'm not having luck. I tried:

```
info.(vals{1:2}).lastcontract
```

without success. I think `arrayfun` may be the appropriate way, but I can't figure out the right syntax.

Comment: `arrayfun` IS a hidden loop and it is slower than an explicit one.

Comment: Don't be a afraid of `for` loops. Sometimes they're perfectly fine and even the most appropriate solution.

Comment: @OlegKomarov but they might be handy for simple one-liners

Comment: @GuntherStruyf In fact, IMO that's their purpose (and maybe some JIT considerations). Now that I think about it, why arrayfun and the likes were introduced in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually possible here to manage without an explicit loop (nor `arrayfun`/`cellfun`):

```
C = struct2cell(info);                  %// Convert to cell array
idx = ismember(fieldnames(info), vals); %// Find fields
C = [C{idx}];                           %// Flatten to structure array
result = [C.lastcontract];              %// Extract values
```

**P.S**
`cellfun` would be more appropriate here than `arrayfun`, because you iterate `vals` (a cell array). For the sake of practice, here's a solution with `cellfun`:

```
result = cellfun(@(x)info.(x).lastcontract, vals);
```

Comment: Very clever, but how efficient is this memory- and performance-wise?