# How to access struct elements in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a struct variable in MATLAB lets say X of size 1x25.
X has a field in it say Y, which is a matrix of size 67x3.
How can I assign only the first column of field Y to another vector say Z?
In other words, I want to have Z az a matrix of size 67x25, which each column in Z X(i).Y(:,1) and i=1:25.
I am looking for a one or two line commands not a for loop to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to replace the first column of each field `Y` in the structure array `X` with a column in `Z`? It's a bit confusing with what you want.

Comment: Try converting the struct array to a cell array as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000072/accessing-data-in-structures-without-loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-7) expansion with a post masking should work:

```
>> X = repmat(struct('Y',rand(67,3)),1,25);
>> Z = [X.Y]; Z = Z(:,1:3:end);
>> size(Z)
ans =
    67    25
```